# Reducing negative fraction

Tags: java, reduce, fractions

So i have a little problem with reducing a negative fraction

This is my reduce code

```
private void reduce() {
    int g = Helper.gcd(this.num, this.den);

    num /= g;
    den /= g;
}
```

For example: 
8/64 gives 1/8

But giving -8/64 let's the program crash

This is my gcd code

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
     while (a != b) {
        if (a > b) {
            a -= b;
        } else {
            b -= a;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Just as side note: such code is really **perfect** for unit testing. That has the big advantage that you directly hop into the debugger in case one of your tests is failing.

Comment: Another minor thingy: a and b are pretty bad names for variables. Give your things names that say what they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract the sign first.

```
private void reduce() {
    boolean neg = (num < 0) != (den < 0);
    num = Math.abs(num);
    den = Math.abs(den);
    // obtain the GCD of the non-negative values.
    int g = Helper.gcd(num, den);

    num /= g;
    den /= g;
    if (neg) num *= -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `gcd` method only works for positive numbers. Negative numbers and zero need to be handled separately.

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    a = Math.abs(a);
    b = Math.abs(b);
    if (a == 0) {
        if (b == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        return b;
    }
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    // The rest is just your code, unchanged.
    while (a != b) {
        if (a > b) {
            a -= b;
        } else {
            b -= a;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```